# Python find closest match out of list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list with tuples of rgb color values:

```
colors = [

(0, 0, 0),
(0, 0, 170),
(0, 170, 0),
(0, 170, 170),
(170, 0, 0),
(170, 0, 170),
(255, 170, 0),
(170, 170, 170),
(85, 85, 85),
(85, 85, 255),
(85, 255, 85),
(85, 255, 255),
(255, 85, 85),
(255, 85, 255),
(255, 255, 85),
(255, 255, 255)

]
```

Now I have a rgb value like `(255, 0, 0)` and want to find the color in the list that matchest it best (I think here it would be `(170, 0, 0)`). Is there a way in Python 2.7 to do this?

OK, I found the solution by gnibbler to be the best one. This is what I did:

```
from functools import partial

def colorDifference(testColor, otherColor):
    difference = 0
    difference += abs(testColor[0]-otherColor[0])
    difference += abs(testColor[1]-otherColor[1])
    difference += abs(testColor[2]-otherColor[2])

    return difference

closestColor = min(colors, key=partial(colorDifference, testColor))
```

Comment: How do you define "best"?

Comment: How do you define "the closest match"? Is it the tuple with the smallest total difference between the corresponding elements?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference has some good info on color differences

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First define your difference function and then use

```
min(colors, key=difference_func)
```

If you need to pass the other color in, you can do it like this

```
from functools import partial
def difference_func(test_color, other_color):
    return ???

result = min(colors, key=partial(difference_func, test_color))
```

Comment: +1 for teaching me about the `key=` argument in `min`, very nice!

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplicity, you can measure similarity between two colors as an [euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between two points in "color cube", like this:

```
import math
def distance(color1, color2):
    return math.sqrt(sum([(e1-e2)**2 for e1, e2 in zip(color1, color2)]))
```

Then you can sort colors using that metrics, and take first element -- the most similar color:

```
def best_match(sample, colors):
    by_distance = sorted(colors, key=lambda c: distance(c, sample))
    return by_distance[0]
```

Testing:

```
>>> best_match((255, 0, 0), colors)
(170, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try sorting, using a lambda?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

colors = [
    (0, 0, 0),     (0, 0, 170),    (0, 170, 0),    (0, 170, 170),
    (170, 0, 0),   (170, 0, 170),  (255, 170, 0),  (170, 170, 170),
    (85, 85, 85),  (85, 85, 255),  (85, 255, 85),  (85, 255, 255),
    (255, 85, 85), (255, 85, 255), (255, 255, 85), (255, 255, 255)
]

def getClosestMatch(c):
    l = sorted(colors, key=lambda x:(\
    0 < x[0] <= c[0],\
    0 < x[1] <= c[1],\
    0 < x[2] <= c[2]),\
    reverse=True)

    return l[0];

if __name__ == '__main__':
    color = (255, 0, 0)
    print getClosestMatch(color)
```